# SQLite3: при вставке (добавлении) элемента как сразу получить его id?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Возможно ли такое, что при добавлении элемента сразу получить его id?

Я сделал так:

```
# Добавление нового сервера
def server_add(self, api_url, server_id):
    self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Keys(key, server_id) VALUES (?, ?);",
                        (api_url, server_id, ))
    self.conn.commit()
    result = self.cursor.execute('SELECT id_server FROM Keys WHERE api_url = ?', (api_url,))
    return result.fetchone()[0]
```

Можно ли проще? Возможно в sql есть уже что-то подобное. Что-то не могу сообразить. А то получается два запроса.

Также буду благодарен за любые комментарии по коду.

Comment: У объекта cursor есть [lastrowid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.lastrowid) для такого

Comment: Супер! Разобрался. Спасибо вам. Так и знал, что что-то подобное должно быть.

Answer (score 1):

Ура. Благодаря комментарию нашёл ответ. Спасибо.

```
def add_server(self, name, api_url, feature=None, max_users=100):
    self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Servers(name, api_url, feature, max_users) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);",
                        (name, api_url, feature, max_users,))
    self.conn.commit()
    return self.cursor.lastrowid
```